# is there a way to use "TO_CHAR" in Hibernate criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to "translate" this query in hibernate criteria.

```
SELECT *
FROM ACCDAT_CALENDAR a
WHERE TO_CHAR(a.DATE,'YYYY') = 2021;
```

can someone help me?
thanks

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069928/jpa-criteria-builder-how-to-replace-and-cast-a-string-to-numeric-in-order-by) on how to call functions with a criteria builder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA criteria builder: how to replace and cast a string to numeric in order-by?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069928/jpa-criteria-builder-how-to-replace-and-cast-a-string-to-numeric-in-order-by)