# Criteria JPA - Call Postgres CAST function

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, criteria

I'm trying to call a Postgres function with Criteria but it's not working. I need to use the `LIKE` clause in a UUID field, so I need to convert into `VARCHAR` first.

The result I need:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE cast(uuid as varchar(36)) like '%1234%';
```

What I'm doing in Criteria:

```java
final Path<UUID> uuidField = from.get("uuid");
var cast = cb.function("cast", String.class, uuidField, cb.literal("as varchar(36)"));
cb.like(cast, String.format("%%%s%%", stringValue));
```

The query which is being generated:

```
HQL: select generatedAlias0 from com.MyTable as generatedAlias0 where function('cast', generatedAlias0.uuid, 'as varchar(36)') like '%1234%' order by generatedAlias0.name asc
```

Error:

```
2022-08-08 18:38:48,549 WARN  [io.ver.cor.imp.BlockedThreadChecker] (vertx-blocked-thread-checker) Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-9,5,main] has been blocked for 2393 ms, time limit is 2000 ms: io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at antlr.ASTFactory.make(ASTFactory.java:342)
    at antlr.ASTFactory.make(ASTFactory.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.jpaFunctionSyntax(HqlBaseParser.java:4633)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.primaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:1075)
```

The log is not so clear (I'm using Quarkus + Hibernate Reactive), but I suspect it crashed in database because the `function('cast', generatedAlias0.uuid, 'as varchar(36)')`.

I think it should be something like: `function('cast', generatedAlias0.uuid, as varchar(36))` (without quotes). But I don't know how to achieve this result to test my theory.

How can I call this `CAST` function?

Comment: create your own postresql  function which won't require 'as varchar()' tail  and call it

Comment: You may need to implement a custom Dialect for postgres, registering the standard cast function. This would not require a PostgreSQL function in the database but only a new class registered against your application

Comment: I just noticed you want to run a "like" against an UUID - think twice if that's what you want to achieve, as it makes no sense I think unless you have a very awkward business requirement and UUID generator (so they are not UUID's really)

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov it's a possible solution. But I think that the project CTO will not like this approach.

Comment: Thanks @HaroldH. I was investigating this option, together with possibility to create a custom function as suggested by @@Andrey. But I found a workaround. I will post the solution. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: @HaroldH You are right. It's very crazy to do LIKE in a UUID. But it's a project requirement. We are doing a new system to replace a previous one and they said that users do a lot of filtering by parts of the UUID. Crazy, but they want.

Comment: Sounds like your managers completely miss the point of what UUID is made for. But anyways, if you need to implement substring search on this attribute, just store it as varchar. If you can't change the original column, just add it as an extra (copy) one.

Answer (score 1):

After investigating some possible solutions (I'm avoiding to create custom database routines) I found something interesting in a answer from another question:

> Currently JPA does not have APIs for replace() and cast(string as numeric). But you can use CriteriaBuilder.function(...) to create database native functions if database portability is not critical.

Source: [JPA criteria builder: how to replace and cast a string to numeric in order-by?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069928/jpa-criteria-builder-how-to-replace-and-cast-a-string-to-numeric-in-order-by)

I don't know if this is documented is some place, but assuming that there is no way to call `CAST(x AS y)` using Criteria, I tried a workaround to force the `UUID` to `VARCHAR` cast without using the probably unsupported `CAST` function.

I tested this direct SQL query to database:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE concat(uuid, '') like '%123%';
```

And it works. This `CONCAT` forces the cast to `VARCHAR` and the `LIKE` function does his job. Knowing this, I did:

```
final Path<UUID> uuidField = from.get("uuid");
var cast = cb.function("concat", String.class, uuidField, cb.literal(""));
cb.like(cast, String.format("%%%s%%", stringValue));
```

Worked perfectly. I hope this help someone else.

As @HaroldH said, it's a weird requirement, but happened in my project.

Comment: I'm afraid you will not be able take advantage of functional index on `concat(uuid, '')` if HBN uses bind variables when executing such SQL queries.